# When linking to extensions in an answer should we point to JED?

Tags: discussion

I was just wondering as many Joomla related questions can be answered with an extension, would it be better practice to link directly to the developers website or to that item in the JED providing it's listed there?

Answer (score 6):

Good question.

Personally I always like to link to JED so that the users gets to see a little information about the extensions, along with user reviews and ratings. If the extension does not suit their needs, then they can simply go to the parent category, where as if they were linked to the developers' site, then they would manually have to search for the category which can make life a little hard as JED is becoming bigger by the day

Answer (score 3):

Maybe both, but I'd personally favour the developers site because that is the definitive source. The JED link is not always reliable for any number of reasons, not least of which the extension could have been unpublished for a trivial non-compliance reason (has happened to me).

Comment: But what about extensions unpublished for non-trivial reasons like security vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that JED is better but I would prefer a link to the JED category so the user can self decide which extension is the right one for him.

But giving 3 links per post is maybe a overkill ;-)